# How to obtain the specific basis functions of the spline term in brms package in R like done in mgcv package?

Tags: r, spline, gam, mgcv, brms

In mgcv package, after fitting a gam model with "age" as a spline term as below

```
fit_mgcv <- gam(wage ~ s(age) + year, data = Wage)
```

I can extract a detailed matrix showing the output value of each basis functions for each observations by the below code.

```
basis_func <- predict(fit_mgcv, type = "lpmatrix")
```

This yields something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLISO.png)
Here, the spline function for variable age has 9 term(basis functions).
I can see the output of each basis functions for the spline function of age when a specific age value (ex.35) is inputed.
And these values are simply the output of the basis function. The coefficients are not multiplied yet.

And with the below code I can visually see each of the 9 basis functions.

```
# Extract age values (or whichever values you've used for the spline)
age_values <- Wage$age

# Only keep the spline-related columns from the lpmatrix
spline_cols <- bf[, grep("s\\(age\\)", colnames(bf))]

# Create a plot for each basis function
matplot(age_values, spline_cols, type = "l", lty = 1,
        xlab = "Age",
        ylab = "Basis Function Value",
        main = "Basis Functions for Age Spline Term")
```

The output is this.
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lecaa.png)

And also if I want to see the specific output of each basis functions for age = 5 and 120, by doing the below code, I can do so.

```
# New code to get basis function values for age = 5 and 120
new_data <- data.frame(age = c(5, 120), year = mean(Wage$year))  # You can replace mean(Wage$year) with a specific year if you prefer
bf_new <- predict(fit_mgcv, newdata = new_data, type = "lpmatrix")
spline_cols_new <- bf_new[, grep("s\\(age\\)", colnames(bf_new))]
spline_cols_new
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iDvU.png)

Also, if I want to specify the specific type of the spline function, I can do so with the below code. I can again visually inspect the basis functions of the spline functions for variable age.

```
fit_mgcv_cr <- gam(wage ~ s(age, bs = "cr") + year, data = Wage)
bf_cr <- predict(fit_mgcv_cr, type = "lpmatrix")
spline_cols_cr <- bf_cr[, grep("s\\(age\\)", colnames(bf_cr))]
# Create a plot for each basis function
matplot(age_values, spline_cols_cr, type = "l", lty = 1,
        xlab = "Age",
        ylab = "Basis Function Value",
        main = "Basis Functions for Age Spline Term")
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CwtT.png)

Now I want to do all these in "brms" package too. This is a similar package again in R but instead implements a bayesian version of mgcv GAM.

In brms, I implement my model as follows

```
formula1 <- brmsformula(wage ~ year + s(age))
simple_lm_brms <- brm(formula = formula1, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data = Wage, seed = 1, chains = 1, iter = 2000)
```

I've tried

```
summary(simple_lm_brms)
```

```
posterior_summary(simple_lm_brms)
```

```
parnames(simple_lm_brms)
```

```
stancode(simple_lm_brms)
```

but none of them gives me back the detailed output of each basis function like I could do in mgcv package.

```
standata_brms <- make_standata(formula = formula1, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data = Wage)
standata_brms$Zs_1_1
```

One thing the I found...
Above code(i.e.standata_brms$Zs_1_1) gave me back a table of 3000 rows and 8 columns.
Zs_1_1 is defined as "basis function matrix" (observed in the output of stancode()).
This may be something relevant to what I want.
But I am not sure what this is.

Even if it is, how can I plot this as a function of age value as I did with mgcv package?

Also, how can I get the value of each basis function when specifying for specific age value like 5 or 120?

Last how can I specify a type of spline function like cubic spline or thin plate spline in brms package?

I would greatly greatly appreciate any kind of help. Thank you very much.